# Why are there no/very-few bicycle-specific lights with replaceable 18650 Li-Ion batteries?

Tags: lighting, headlights, battery

Most (higher end) battery-powered bicycle lights have built-in Li-Ion battery or a battery pack nowadays. There seem to be no front lights using replaceable 18650 cells. Rear lights with replaceable batteries are widely available in my area (EU).

Li-Ion batteries have limited life and as such they limit lifetime of the whole light. If used everyday, the capacity is gone in one year. With replaceable batteries I can carry spare charged units for long night rides. 18650 batteries are widely available and seem to be natural "successors" of NiMh AA batteries for applications like bike lights, but such "evolution" didn't happen.

Is there any **technical** (not marketing) reason for this?

(I also use dynamo lights. This question is specifically about 18650 batteries.)

Comment: It took me many more words to ask a similar question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/69923/48599

Comment: As of this writing, I do know of [one such light](https://www.fenixlight.com/product/detail/index.php?id=79)

Comment: There are plenty of flashlights/torches using such batteries, but they generally make for poor bike lights.  The tech definitely exists.

Comment: I personally use an external battery pack light. The batteries are obviously easily replaceable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get a bright rear light using AA batteries, or is there a compelling reason why nonreplaceable batteries are so widespread?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/69923/can-i-get-a-bright-rear-light-using-aa-batteries-or-is-there-a-compelling-reaso)

Comment: @ojs In my area (EU) rear lights using AA batteries are not uncommon at all, so that question didn't apply to me.

Comment: @KonstantinShemyak ok, I thought the same engineering considerations would apply to both front and rear lights. BTW, I live in EU too and most rear LEDs available here don't have replaceable batteries.

Comment: @ojs There are still plenty that do have them. Some people do not bother replacing the hidded cr 2032 batteries in small ones, but it does not make them non-replaceable. All of these should have recharheable batteries https://www.bike-eshop.cz/svetla-na-kolo#filtrace&shsor=&cod=&cdo=&ps=&pn=&pz=&pg=1&pp=&pvz_339=8094

Comment: @VladimirF ok, let's narrow it down. I live in part of EU that is not Czech Republic :)

Comment: @ojs First sorry for the mistake, they have replaceable, not "recharheable". The EU is a one joint market so everything is essentially available everywhere even though the postage might be expensive sometimes. I used to shop in a UK-based e-shop quite often.

Comment: @VladimirF I get that, but I really don't get why I would order a light that uses one of those awful coin cells from CZ when I can buy one that's rechargeable with standard USB cable from sports store next door.

Comment: For clarification: I think the OP is asking why we don't have many bike lights with removable, standard format batteries, e.g. AA or 18650. And for info, it seems that 18650 is a different size than AA. I can find rechargeable lithium ion AA batteries on Amazon, and I still have some AA NiCd batteries that I use in my bluetooth mouse and keyboard. Also, I see some 2032 rechargeable batteries also, but I was mainly familiar with 2032 as a single-use battery.

Comment: @WeiwenNg The [previous question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/69923/can-i-get-a-bright-rear-light-using-aa-batteries-or-is-there-a-compelling-reaso) was about AA and AAA, this one is 18650 specifically. The cr2032 is just noise, I just was not filter just AA and AAA in that particular eshop (shows all removable instead) when I showed ojs that there are still plenty such lights (AA and AAA).

Comment: The lack of a standard, the use of proprietary standards (e.g.: https://www.milwaukeetool.com/Products/Batteries-and-Chargers/M18-Batteries-and-Chargers/48-11-1820 ) for power tools, and sealing the battery inside a device—portable lights and other devices—all mean that we will generate (20 years from now when all is this is thrown out) an enormous amount of garbage.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a disposable or one-time use or "primary" 18650 battery?   I think not, or they're exceedingly rare.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technical reasons: It’s harder and more expensive to design and manufacture a sturdy, lightweight, waterproof case which can be opened by the user. It’s also harder to design and manufacture spring loaded battery contacts which work reliably under heavy vibrations.

Most lights come with a built-in charging controller and can be conveniently charged via Micro USB or some other connector. Some 18650 batteries are only rated for certain voltages or currents which would make it harder to implement this fool-proof.

---

Personally I would be totally fine with having to open a few screws to access the battery. I’d also be fine with having to pick the right battery and not having a fool-proof connector style as long as the manufacturer tells me which batteries are compatible and the batteries are easily and cheaply available. But it seems there is just not enough demand and most consumers are fine with replacing whole devices every 4 years or so when the battery goes bad.

Comment: I fully support all arguments in this answer. But for example head lights (I mean, which are put on the head) with replaceable 18650 battery are quite common, while all these arguments equally apply. What makes bike lights different?

Comment: Perhaps there is a gap where 18650 is vastly overpowered for regular cycling lights with intensity levels legal on-street in Europe, but inadequate for incredibly powerful offroad lights?  Only someone who actually works at a bike light manufacturer could really provide the authoritative answer on why they feel there isn't enough market for such a product.

Answer (score 5):

As Criggie notes, there are plenty of flashlights using such batteries, and I find some make excellent headlights. I've mounted such lights to my handlebar and/or to my helmet.

The characteristics I find useful are:

1. Good quality machining of the aluminum shell, and O-rings to prevent water ingress.
2. Multiple brightness modes, including both high-lumen flood (perhaps 200 lumens) and medium/low lumen blinking. High-lumen mode should last at least 1-2 hours on a single 18650 charge.
3. Wide flood with uniform illumination over the field rather than a strong center bright spot and weak illumination to sides. A wide zoom range with quality glass lens can work well for this.
4. Sufficient builtin heat dissipation that LED can run at high lumens for more than an hour without either LED or battery having overheating issues.

Comment: There are countless such headlights. Replacable is the rule there, not the exception (in the higher quality and brightness sector). But the question is, why there are no such bike lights? Or are there any?

Comment: @VladimirF I have found it difficult to get such a flashlight with char. (3) above - a wide, uniform illumination field, and sometimes the other char. as well. In any case, what do you mean by a "bike light"? I consider my flashlights (and their mounts) "bike lights" and dedicate them for that purpose.

Comment: Well if I take my caving helmet with the screwed-on custom headlight I also get "a bike light". But I assume the question was about dedicated bike lights, especially those that are intended to be optionally mounted on the bike itself, not any general-purpose lights.

Comment: @VladimirF I guess that's my point - I don't see anything that makes my lighting systems different from whatever a "bike light" is other than marketing.

Comment: After juhist arrrives, he will explain to you that a proper bike light must follow the German norm that prescribes the way the light cone is illuminated to avoid blinding other traffic. Even if you leave that issue aside, a proper bike light - for me - comes with a possibility to be mounted directly on a bicycle without resorting to various bodges or inventing custom 3d printed mounts.

Comment: You are likely correct about the first part, on the second I consider my $10 ebay/amazon handlebar light mounts neither bodgy nor 3d-printed. Perhaps I should instead obtain titanium ones for proper bike community approval :)

Comment: @VladimirF ... and soon afterwards someone else will surely point out that attaching a solid metal object to one's helmet and so close to one's cranium fails to comply with various DIN/ANSI/ISO standards. At the very least the flashlight should be made from collapsible material.

Comment: I’m not juhist but I have to agree with Vladimir. Not blinding other traffic is important and for that you need a proper horizontal cut-off. A circular light cone (as it’s typically found on handheld flashlights) is completely unsuitable for road use, unless it’s very low power and only there to make you more visible.

Comment: @Michael As long as the handlebar mount is adjustable both for horizontal angle and for vertical angle, I found it straightforward to angle a flashlight down and slightly outward (away from the other traffic direction). Probably 90%+ of my riding is on paths/multiuse trails/sidewalks rather than roads, and I haven't yet had problems blinding oncoming traffic. I think most sensible riders can quickly evaluate whether a given setup will cause such issues or not.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the main reason for not allowing swappable batteries in modern 18650-based lights is profit on the manufacturers side.

I have a 12 year old bike light that takes 4 x AA batteries. I use rechargeable NiMh and during the past 12 years I bought a few new sets of rechargeable AA NiMh batteries.

The point is that I just replace the batteries and the manufacturer makes no money. If the batteries would be builtin then I'd have to buy new bike lights and the manufacturer would make money. Somehow the manufacturers have realized this and seem to be pushing for this approach.

However, from the point of view of the environment and amount of garbage we produce; I guess it's much better to replace batteries and dispose them properly then make a whole new bike light but that is a different story.

Comment: The question is specifically about 18650 Li-ion, not AA NiMH

Comment: NiMH are just an example here. My response is applicable to all type of batteries, including 18650 Li-ion.

Comment: Did you read the question? If you did not understand why it is not applicable to all types of batteries, read it again.

Comment: The question was: "Why are there no/very-few bicycle-specific lights with replaceable 18650 Li-Ion batteries?" and "18650 batteries are widely available and seem to be natural "successors" of NiMh AA batteries for applications like bike lights, but such "evolution" didn't happen." Now, I gave my experience with AA batteries and my opinion why we do not have bike lights with replaceable batteries today. My reasoning applies to 18650 batteries as well. In short, the "evolution" didn't happen because it would mean a financial drawback for the manufacturer.

Comment: there is one detail in your answer that completely invalidates it. Can you find it?

Comment: The question specifies "Is there any technical (not marketing) reason for this?"  And I suspect the answer hidden in here is "No."   AA batteries, and C or D batteries before that have been designed for swapping since forever.  The additional power density of a modern rechargeable was not available in older battery chemistry.

Answer (score -3):

I use this head mounted light that uses 18650 batteries.

It doesn't need to be mounted on bike, thus can not be stolen.

[image]

From  https://www.ebay.com/itm/254653073362

Comment: That’s only suitable for off-road use because it blinds other road users.

Comment: Not if it has adjustable light levels which most do. @Michael

Comment: Are you affiliated with the seller? It makes no sense to post some particular type of headlight. It also does not answer the actual answer asked.

Comment: It's a good point, but is also not a bike-specific light, and has the potential to be misused on the road.  However these kinds of rigs would be more found in off-road usage, where the enormous illumination/spill is definitely useful.

Comment: @Michael off road riding is still riding.  We accept both kinds, so I'm going to leave this as an answer.  It would be a poor choice to ride with this kind of light on the road.

Comment: Aside - the image shows red lights forward, which is generally illegal.  If you choose to ride something like this, red=rear and white=front.  You can use yellow/amber in any direction.